# c++ kdtree for nearest 3D triangle search?

Tags: c++, search, kdtree

I've found a ton of libraries out there for doing kdtree nearest neighbor searches on a cloud of points.

I've also found a good number of kdtree libraries for doing ray->triangle hit tests.

However, I can't seem to find any information about how to efficiently do a nearest-triangle search using a kdtree. Does such a library exist? Or is there a different type of data structure other than a kdtree that is ideal for this kind of NN search?

Comment: Are you dealing with 2D or higher-dimensional data? In 2D there should be no difference between nearest triangle and nearest line segment searches. In any case I think you should look at PMR quadtrees (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/pubs/NelsSIGG86.pdf has the 2D case nailed down, and references to implementations in higher dimensions).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I need a method for 3d triangles. I've edited the title.